# Which function will it call?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operators, operator-overloading

Here is the code, I wrote the comments. 
The question is I don't know which function will be called after the function unhide in the Derive class.

```
    #include <CONIO.H>
    #include <IOSTREAM>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    class Base
    {
        string strName;
    public:
        Base& operator=(const Base &b)
        {
            this->strName = b.strName;
            cout << "copy assignment" << endl;
            return *this;
        }
        Base& operator=(string& str)
        {
            this->strName = str;
            cout << "operator=(string& str)" << endl;
            return *this;
        }

    };

    class Derive : public Base
    {
    public:
        int num;
        using Base::operator =; // unhide Base::operator=();
    };

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        Derive derive1;
        derive1.num = 1;

        Derive derive2;

        Base b1;
        derive1 = b1;  // This will call Base& Base::operator=(const Base &b)
                           //no problem

        string str("test");
        derive1 = str;  // This will call Base& Base::operator=(string& str)
                            // no problem

        derive2 = derive1; // What function will this statement call???
                               // If it calls Base& Base::operator(const Base &b)
                               // how could it be assigend to a class Derive?
        return 0;
    }
```

But the result of the code is: derive2.num equals to 1!!!, that means the whole class has been copied after the statment, why would this happen?

**Thanks to Tony, I think I got the answer.**

***here is my explanation:***

Based on C++0x 7.3.3.3 and 12.8.10, The using-statement in `Derive` will be explained like this

```
class Derive : public Base
{
public:
    int num;
    //using Base::operator =;
    Base& operator=(const Base &b); // comes form the using-statement
    Base& operator=(string& str); // comes form the using-statement
    Derive& operator=(const Derive &); // implicitly declared by complier
};
```

So when I wrote:

```
string str("test");
derive1 = str;
```

function `Base& Base::operator=(string& str);` will be called,

and when I wrote:

```
Base b1;
derive1 = b1;
```

function `Base& Base::operator=(const Base &b);` will be called,

finnaly, when I wrote:

```
derive2 = derive1;
```

function `Derive& Dervie::operator=(const Derive&);` will be called.

Comment: What happens when you try it out?

Comment: @aioobe derive1 is correctly coppied to derive2, I can't explain it

Comment: I am just concerned about your compiler and platform. On my win7/vs2008, the result shows that derive2.num will be some random value instead of 1.

Comment: @winterTTr I'm using winxp/mingw(from Qt4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard 7.3.3-4 (from an old draft, but in this regard still valid):

> If an assignment operator brought from a base class into a derived class scope has the signature of a copy-assignment operator for the derived class (class.copy), the using-declaration does not by itself suppress the implicit declaration of the derived class copy-assignment operator; the copy-assignment operator from the base class is hidden or overridden by the implicitly-declared copy-assignment operator of the derived class, as described below.

So, the implicit `Derived::operator=()` is used.

Comment: @shengy: I'm no idea where "below" meant- there's nothing *immediately* below that paragraph of apparent relevance.  You might like to look at one of the freely-available draft Standards yourself: e.g. C++0x at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the question, and wrote my understanding in it

Comment: @shengy: yup - that pretty much sums it up.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It will call the derived `operator=`, which in its automatically generated implementation will call `operator=` from `Base` as well as copy the members in `Derive`.

Comment: so you mean it will call Base& Base::operator()?? But if it calls that function, HOW COULD Derive.num be copied correctly?

Comment: @shengy: The automatically generated `operator=` copies it. Try adding your own `Derive &Derive::operator=` and see how the behavior changes.

Comment: @shengy: calling `Base::operator=()` is only one of the things that the implicitly created `Derived::operator=()` does... it goes on to copy the members.